# Converting .csv file to xlsx adds <> to fields

Tags: c#, excel, csv, oledb

I opened a csv file in Excel and then converted it to an xlsx file so that we can import it into our system via the OLEDB interface via C#.

It is a simple query we do `select * from [anyworksheet]` to populate a datatable object. However, after the conversion we receive an error. This happens for different column types:

- DateTime: Cannot parse <15-01-2015> as a DateTime
- Int (null entry): Cannot parse < > as an Int

I checked the csv file and it doesn't contain <> in the fields, and have tried to force datetime formatting on the cells in the excel file and it didn't work.

Can you at least tell me what is happening here, even if there isn't a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the `<` and `>` only appear as part of the error message to make it clear what is the actual value. Think of them as quotes.

In your examples neither is a space an integer and can be parsed as such, nor is your date format anything sensible. So it doesn't surprise me that you get errors. For dates try using ISO-8601, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD, which should work much better in an interchange format.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use ClosedXML library.
It is simpler than OLEdb and doesn't limit string length to 255 characters.